# Visual Studio: Prevent DOM Explorer from opening when debugging Windows Store app

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

When debugging a Windows Store app, written in HTML/JS/CSS, every time I press "debug" it launches the DOM Explorer window; which is not always desired (I'd rather open it manually). Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what caused the DOM Explorer to open but try going to this menu while debugging Debug > Windows > DOM Explorer. Here is the documentation on the DOM Explorer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441474.aspx. If you include a screenshot of what you are seeing I might be able to help you more if that didn't solve the problem. This question isn't related to WinJS so I recommend you remove the WinJS tag.